# Why do I always start an application in Django I do not see the CSS style?

Tags: python, css, django

I would like to know what the problem is with the CSS style of my applications. Every time I start a new application CSS style never appears and I check the configurations with my colleagues and they are practically the same. Does anyone know why this is due? We use the same version of Python (3.4.4) and Django (1.8).

*My setting.py file:*

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'app_name',
    )

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR)],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
```

I have not started with anything yet from the other configurations (urls.py or models.py).

Thank you for all your contributions.

Comment: Without adding some code or a more clear explanation people won't be able to help you very easily.

Comment: @BenHare Thank you, I will edit the question

Comment: Please add the template used, also, is there a .css file under the static URL?

Comment: Do you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Please post your _whole_ `settings.py` and also your `urls.py`. Is the DEBUG setting enabled or not?

Comment: What you meant here by everytime i start `application`, you mean running the development server with `runserver` or you meant `startapp` ?
it is better if you give DEBUG status, your friends settings file is also same & they dont have any problem ?

Comment: @sideffect I tried to say that by executing the runserver command the admin site never loads the CSS style that Django has by default only the HTML. My colleagues can see the CSS style without having to put any extra settings, basically we have the same settings in the settings.py file and start the same applications and projects in the same way.

Comment: @E.Lizbeth May be your settings DEBUG=False or missing